# SQL Server Reporting Services Incompatible

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ssrs-2008

I have a Visual Studio 2015 C# MVC project that attaches to SQL Server 2008 R2. I have the most updated Entity Framework and SSDT versions available on my local machine.

In the project solution, I also have a `.rptproj` that's all built and ready to use. However, when I go to the `mySQLServer/Reports/` URL and try to upload the `.rptproj` file from my projects folder, I get this error:

> The report definition is not valid or supported by this version of
>   Reporting Services. This could be the result of publishing a report
>   definition of a later version of Reporting Services, or that the
>   report definition contains XML that is not well-formed or the XML is
>   not valid based on the Report Definition schema. Details: The report
>   definition has an invalid target namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition'
>   which cannot be upgraded. (rsInvalidReportDefinition)

My server is running .NET Framework version 3.5.1 with WCF, HTTP, and non-HTTP activation (if those matter at all). I tried doing some research as to what could cause this specifically, and have found no good resolutions from either Microsoft nor the public community thus far. What could be causing my SQL Server to reject my Report Project?

Edit:

In regards to @TabAlleman comment, here is my Deployment Properties of my Report Project in Visual Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are deploying reports to a 2008 R2 SQL Server, you need to build the reports in BIDS 2008.

Comment: Do you have a link to some documentation or a quick personal synapsis on how I would make it do that? I've done some MVC work before, but it was by all means basic, and control the SSRS is something I'm entirely new to (got the responsibility to maintain some old code dumped on me rather suddenly)

Comment: No I don't have anything handy.   I've never done MVC work, but I know this much about SSRS.